# Get Facebook app scoped id from page scoped id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I configured Facebook messenger webhook and Facebook Page tab webhook. I am trying to group facebook posts and facebook messages based on user. But, I get page scoped id from messenger webhook and app scoped id from page tab webhook. Both are different. I found a way to link them by using profile image URL, which is not an ideal way, because if user changes profile image, URL changes. Can any one suggest other way to link app scoped id using page scoped id?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible; If Facebook wanted you to be able to make that connection, they would probably not have introduced page-scoped ids in the first place. If you have your own login system within your app, then perhaps you could use account linking to synchronize the two, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking

Comment: Howdy. I am trying to get a fb profile url, or an app-scoped id from a user talking to my messenger bot. I have the user's page-scoped id. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is a bit old, but seeing there is no answer yet. Take a look at ID matching API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts.

You need to link your page and app to a facebook business and then you will be able to call the api to get corresponding app scoped id - page scoped id pairs.

Answer (score -1):

This is only possible if you are the owner of the page and application. If the page is third party it will not be listed as part of the deal.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.